# How to use a columns values from a dataframe as keys to keep rows from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes - one with 60 rows and another with 65 rows. I would like to have both the tables with equal rows and use Date column of the smaller dataframe as keys to delete columns from the larger dataframe. As a snippet:

df1

```
         Date|Price
 Apr 01, 2021|73
 Mar 31, 2021|74
 Mar 30, 2021|72
 Mar 29, 2021|71
 Mar 27, 2021|73
```

df2:

```
         Date|Price
 Apr 01, 2021|43
 Mar 31, 2021|54
 Mar 30, 2021|62
 Mar 29, 2021|41
 Mar 27, 2021|53
 Mar 25, 2021|61
 Mar 24, 2021|73
```

expected output for df2:

```
         Date|Price
 Apr 01, 2021|43
 Mar 31, 2021|54
 Mar 30, 2021|62
 Mar 29, 2021|41
 Mar 27, 2021|53
```

I want to keep the values in df1 while have only those values from df2 which have same date as df1 and drop the rest. (My idea is to have two dataframes of equal length - and from date column, both the tables should be same)

I came across solutions like:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()
```

and

```
cond = df1['Date'].isin(df2['Date'])
df1.drop(df1[cond].index, inplace = True)
```

But they donot yield desired result.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Can you please provide your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`isin()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) but with this logic instead.

Mark the indexes where `df2.Date` is in `df1.Date` and return those rows from `df2`:

```py
df2 = df2[df2.Date.isin(df1.Date)]

#            Date  Price
# 0  Apr 01, 2021     43
# 1  Mar 31, 2021     54
# 2  Mar 30, 2021     62
# 3  Mar 29, 2021     41
# 4  Mar 27, 2021     53
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2,indicator = True)
out = out[out['_merge'] == 'both']
```

Then we have the column `_merge`, you can then filter it with 'both'

Comment: Hello - thanks for reply. I have updated my desired outcome, could you please let me know if the code you said would produce the desired outcome? Thanks again.